# Recover Gmail address

Tags: gmail, google-account, account-recovery

I have a Gmail email address but have forgotten it? How can I find out what it was?

Answer (score 1):

Do you remember and have access to the secondary email address that you provided while registering this email address? If Yes, then you can go to "Forgot Email address" option within the "I can't access my account" option in the GMail Sign In Page, give your secondary email address and receive an email from Google containing the list of all your associated email addresses.

Anyhow, if you do not know your secondary email addresses, checking for trails of previous usage, for example asking from friends and family with whom you have exchanged emails is the only way to remember it back.